# UICollectionView frame Height is not same as it is in Xib Inspector

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview

My storyboard have one collection view. In sizeForItem delegate method, I printed collectionView Frame height, which comes out as 769. But when i inspected XIB, it is 741. Please explain the difference.
[image]

Then I inspected in XIB. And height is showing 741.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Root-cause:**
In your case problem is sizeForItemAtIndexPath is being called before ViewDidLayoutSubviews.
To get the actual size wait for ViewDidLayoutSubviews,

**Solution:**
Try to reload CollectionView after ViewDidLayoutSubviews (It's not a great solution but....)